# XML merge nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<Root>    
        <Item>
          <CityCode>ALV</CityCode>
          <AirportCode>ALV</AirportCode>
          <CityName>ANDORRA LA VELLA</CityName>
          <AirportName>Andorra La Vella Hlpt</AirportName>
          <StateCode></StateCode>
          <CountryCode>AD</CountryCode>
          <AirportTypeCode>8</AirportTypeCode>
          <AirportTypeName>Heliport, not scheduled</AirportTypeName>    
       </Item>       
</Root>
```

and i need a xslt to get this:

```
<Root>
   <Item>
     <CityCode>ALV</CityCode>
     <CityName>ANDORRA LA VELLA</CityName>
     <CityNameComplete> ANDORRA LA VELLA (ALV) - Andorra La Vella Hlpt </CityNameComplete>
   <Item>
<Root>
```

I know how to get the first 2 nodes, I don't know how to "insert" the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that can handle missing `<AirportCode>` and/or `<AirportName>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity template. Matches everything that isn't matched
        by another template and copies it without modification.-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <!--Copy the current element (Item) to the output.-->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--Apply templates to attributes of Item and also the
            CityCode and CityName elements. All other nodes of
            Item will not be processed.-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CityCode|CityName|@*"/>
            <CityNameComplete>
                <!--Output the value of CityName.-->
                <xsl:value-of select="CityName"/>
                <!--Apply the template for AirportCode. If it doesn't exist,
                nothing will be output.-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="AirportCode"/>
                <!--Apply the template for AirportName. If it doesn't exist,
                nothing will be output.-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="AirportName"/>
            </CityNameComplete>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AirportCode">
        <!--Output the value of AirportCode, surrounded by parenthesis and
        preceded by a space.-->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' (',.,')')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AirportName">
        <!--Output the value of AirportName, preceded by a "space dash space".-->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' - ',.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where's a detailed explanation on how this works? As it is, this answer isn't very helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - The code was simple enough I didn't think it warranted a detailed explanation. The OP didn't have any questions before accepting the answer and any future visitor could've also asked for clarification. I added comments to explain what the code is doing. If you have a specific question that isn't covered by the comments, please let me know.

Comment: Ah, well, more often than not, one constant of the internet is that the original answer author will not respond any more by the time a future visitor actually asks something ;-) Better to supply explanations right away, before it is too late.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to embed this into your complete XSLT, but let's say that you consider the `<CityNameComplete>` element as a replacement of the `<AirportName>` element from the original Xml document.

Then, the key is XSLT's `<value-of>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root/Item/AirportName">
    <CityNameComplete><xsl:value-of select="../CityName"/> (<xsl:value-of select="../AirportCode"/>) - <xsl:value-of select="."/></CityNameComplete>
</xsl:template>
```

This will yield a

```
<CityNameComplete>ANDORRA LA VELLA (ALV) - Andorra La Vella Hlpt</CityNameComplete>
```

element in the result.

**Update:** If you really want the whitespace around the complete city name, add it with `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` in the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root/Item/AirportName">
    <CityNameComplete><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../CityName"/> (<xsl:value-of select="../AirportCode"/>) - <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></CityNameComplete>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<CityNameComplete> ANDORRA LA VELLA (ALV) - Andorra La Vella Hlpt </CityNameComplete>
```

**Update 2:** Included the IATA code.

**Update 3:** An alternative solution for inserting the node is to add it in the template for the `<Item>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root/Item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <CityNameComplete><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="CityName"/> (<xsl:value-of select="AirportCode"/>) - <xsl:value-of select="AirportName"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></CityNameComplete>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that you have to remove the nodes that you don't want to exactly get your output - as you did not ask for that, and as I didn't want to clutter the answer, I haven't included any code on how to do so.

Comment: I managed to remove the nodes I don't need, but I'm not really sure how to keep the Root and Item. My output is this: <CityCode>ALV</CityCode>     
<CityName>ANDORRA LA VELLA</CityName>      
<CityNameComplete> ANDORRA LA VELLA (ALV) - Andorra La Vella Hlpt </CityNameComplete>

Comment: @OanaAnton: Please see the explanations on the XSLT identity template, e.g. here: http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=492 It essentially copies the whole contents of the source Xml document to the output, except for the nodes that are matched by other templates in your XSLT.

Comment: @Mapper: Thanks for the help. It's the 1st time I work with XML, XSLT and everything is new. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to build upon the identity template, and have an extra template to match the **item** element in which you then output the **CityNameComplete** element using the **concat** function:

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <Item>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     <CityNameComplete>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(CityName, ' (', AirportCode, ') ', AirportName)"/>
     </CityNameComplete>
  </Item>
</xsl:template>
```

You would also need a template to ignore all the elements you don't want to output. In this case everything other than the **CityCode** and **CityName** elements

```
<xsl:template match="Item/*[not(self::CityCode|self::CityName)]"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="Item/*[not(self::CityCode|self::CityName)]"/>

   <xsl:template match="Item">
      <Item>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         <CityNameComplete>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(CityName, ' (', AirportCode, ') ', AirportName)"/>
         </CityNameComplete>
      </Item>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following is output

```
<Root>
   <Item>
     <CityCode>ALV</CityCode>
     <CityName>ANDORRA LA VELLA</CityName>
     <CityNameComplete>ANDORRA LA VELLA (ALV) Andorra La Vella Hlpt</CityNameComplete>
   </Item>
</Root>
```